# How can I cleanup least frequently used python packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My system has 1000s of python packages installed. Now I want to cleanup least frequently used python packages how do I proceed. Is there any package which can track the usage of these over time and help me identify those to be cleaned up.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this- roughly how many of these 1000s of packages do you actually need? might be worth starting from a fresh install

Comment: @h4z3 isn't it too naive to think someone who has been working on python over a `decade` and hence accumulated 1000+ global packages isn't familiar with virtual environments. if I wasn't using different environments would have accumulated 100k packages by now.